# angularjs - Problems With Uploading Images

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a solid way i can upload images asynchronously? I cant seem to get this working for some reason,,,I've tried third-party plugins but still no luck. Could someone help me get moving??

Comment: You don't really need any plugins, it's about 10 lines of code if you use FormData.

Comment: check out ng-flow, it works very well https://github.com/flowjs/ng-flow